# Crear archivo con contenido Hexadecimal y ASCII en nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Necesito crear un archivo plano con un string que contiene hexadecimal y en su mayor parte ASCII.
El string es algo como:

```
var a = "var x = '\x68\x6F\x6C\x61\x61\x61\x61\x20\x6D\x75\x6E\x64\x69\x6C\x6C\x6F\x6F\x6F\x6F\x6F'";
```

El contenido de la variable `a` intento escribirlo en un archivo, pero al momento de crear el archivo todo el contenido hexadecimal se convierte a ASCII. :(

ya intenté modificar el string reemplazando el `\` por doble `\\` pero no funciona debido a que la variable ya fue interpretada y no es hexadecimal.

Así es como genero el archivo:

```
fs.writeFile('paht/file.js', a, 'utf8', function(e, r){
                console.log('litoooo');
            });
```

Ya probé cambiando la codificación a `hex` pero tampoco funciona.

Al final la salida del archivo siempre es:

```
var x = 'holaaaa mundillooooo'
```

Comment: probé tu código y al escapar cada \ poniendo \\ me guardó en el archivo var x = '\x68\x6F\x6C\x61\x61\x61\x61\x20\x6D\x75\x6E\x64\x69\x6C\x6C\x6F\x6F\x6F\x6F\x6F'

Comment: si lo haces de forma manual si funciona, el problema es que el contenido es dinamico, viene precisamente de una petición. 
por eso la funcion replace no funciona porque la variable ya ha sido interpretada.

Answer (score 0):

new Buffer("aqui mi texto", "hex");

Después lo guardas a un archivo

Comment: Guarda el archivo en blanco, lo estoy probando asi:
var n = new Buffer(a,'hex');
fs.writeFile('paht/file.js', n, 'utf8', function(e, r){
                console.log('litoooo');
            });
Yo creo que es por que el contenido de la variable a no es 100% hexadecimal.

Comment: Por qué entonces no separas el hexadecimal y el Unicode, luego lo concatenas en una con formato homogéneo

Comment: porque no sé que es hexadecimal y que no... y cuando trato de procesarlo con alguna función como replace ya no es hexadecimal.